# se pueden leer Imagenes Geotiff con Pil en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagen, pillow

¿Se podrá leer los datos de una imagen geotiff con PIL en Python 3.7?, hago la consulta por que no hay caso con poder instalar el modulo GDAL.  Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Entiendo que no, a menos que escribas un decoder personalizado. Investiga `rasterio`, que es una librería justo para ese tipo de archivos... Que sigue siendo GDAL

Comment: Gracias, ha funcionado hasta el momento